# Why moving platform script is not working?

Tags: unity, platformer, moving-platforms

I have some code attached to a moving platform:

```
public Transform pos1, pos2;
public float speed;
public Transform startPos;

Vector3 nextPos;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    nextPos = startPos.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (transform.position == pos1.position)
    {
        nextPos = pos2.position;
    }
    else if (transform.position == pos2.position)
    {
        nextPos = pos1.position;
    }
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.DrawLine(pos1.position, pos2.position);
}
```

But my platform does not go to the pos2 when it reaches the pos1. What is wrong here?

Comment: When do you tell your platform to move toward pos1? All I see is it moving toward startPos. If startPos does not coincide with pos1, then your platdorm never moves to the position that the first if condition is checking for

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how "MoveTowards" method works, but if you're working on floats then most likely you'll never have exact match of positions.

When doing path followers, I always check the distance between current position and target (pseudocode):

```
if (VectorLength(transform.position-pos1.position) < speed*Time.deltaTime)
{
    nextPos = pos2.position;
}
```

Comment: Unity already takes floating point precision into account when comparing vectors, and also does what your code snippet does in MoveTowards.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @crueltear's answer, I just wanted to provide some code that you might add in your script:

Since it is likely that the `transform.position` `pos1.position` will not perfectly match, try and add a bit of "discrepancy" so that instead of waiting for the positions to match perfectly you just have to wait for them to be within a certain distance.

Try and introduce a `float`, e.g. `public float 
gapDistance` and replace in your if statements

```
(transform.position == pos1.position)
```

With

```
(Vector3.Distance(transform.position , pos1.position) <= gapDistance)
```

Do the same for `pos2.position`. If you are using 2D Vectors instead of 3D, just change `Vector3` with `Vector2`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a few debug logs in update to see what it’s doing.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (transform.position == pos1.position)
    {
        nextPos = pos2.position;
        Debug.Log("Starting move to pos2 at " +  nextPos);
    }
    else if (transform.position == pos2.position)
    {
        nextPos = pos1.position;
        Debug.Log("Starting move to pos1 at " +  nextPos);
    }
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    Debug.Log("move towards " + nextPos + "; new position is " + transform.position);
}
```

Check the console to see what is getting logged.